# Cannot open M.U.G.E.N via Form

Tags: c#, .net

While working on my M.U.G.E.N tournament manager (and after mastering the Quick VS commands), it appears that I cannot run the game within the code.

> Error message: Can't open config file data/mugen.cfg.
>
> Error reading data/mugen.cfg

Here is the code for the process:

```
var proc = Process.Start(SettingsInit.Default.GameDir + "\\mugen.exe","-p1 \"" + folder1 + "\\" + folder1 + ".def\" -p2 \"" + folder2 + "\\" + folder2 + ".def\" -p1.ai 1 -p2.ai 1 -rounds " + SettingsInit.Default.Rounds.ToString() + " -s " + stage + " -log match.txt");
```

This is an example output, which is similar to my current M.U.G.E.N build:

> C:\Users\username\Desktop\MUGEN 1.1\mugen.exe -p1 "Sonic\Sonic.def" -p2 "Shadow\Shadow.def" -p1.ai 1 -p2.ai 2 -rounds 2 -s "Green Hill Zone" -log match.txt

When I run it via CMD, it runs perfectly. After checking with Process Explorer, I found out that the access to information (path, command, etc.) has been denied. Any ideas how VS prevents the game from loading the config file?

It has NOTHING to do with wrong/missing escape sequences and missing admin privileges, since I'm running VS as administrator.

It would be helpful if someone, who works with both M.U.G.E.N and C#, knows the answer to this problem.

Comment: Always a bad idea to use string concatenation to build your file path. Use instead System.Path.Combine

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved!
After specifying domain, username and password in StartInfo (the latter has been hard-coded for now, but I'm already looking for a convenient solution), I was able to get the game to run. It seems as if VS is starting a process with a special user and M.U.G.E.N requires the currently active user to locate the config file.

By the way, thanks, Kevin, for reminding me about string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

in my case this code work's only using

```
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = "Your mugen directory"
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32913920)